# Laravel datatables raw columns

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-blade, laravel-datatables

i have a code like this to display an action button for datatables

```
->addColumn('action', function () {
            return '<form id="delete" action="{{ route(' . 'admin.posts.destroy' . ', $model) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method("DELETE")
            <a href="{{route(' . 'admin.posts.edit' . ', $model) }}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
        </form>';
        })
```

But the `@csrf` and `@method("DELETE")` become a string/text (not method). I tried to append `{{ }}` in `@csrf` and `@method("DELETE")` but it doesn't work. How to change that text to method in blade templates **without make a new view** for action button like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@csrf` replace with `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` and
`@method("DELETE")` with `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">`